# Load cakePHP Element from jQuery

Tags: cakephp, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

I am using cakePHP rating plugin with Flowplayer. I have customized the Flowplayer using the Javascript API. Now I need to display the rating element on the customized Flowplayer. In my other views, I am showing the rating element as given below :

```
echo $this->element('rating', array('plugin' => 'rating',
        'model' => 'SongDetail',
        'id' =>$song_id,
        'name'=>'songRating',
        'config' => 'plugin_rating'
    ));
```

and it is working fine. Now inthe case of flowplayer,I am loading songs using AJAX with jQuery and so the song_id variable is available only in Javascript.How can I call this same element from a Javascript function so that this can be inserted using innerHTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a special action that you call with the `song_id` as parameter. Then end that action with:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->render('/elements/<elementname>');
```

This will make CakePHP render an element in stead of a view. Using the AJAX layout will mean that it's only the element (and no menus and footers etc) that is rendered.

See documentation for `$this->render` in [the CakePHP Book](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render).

Comment: Actually the element I am trying to load contains the following code   '  echo $this->requestAction('rating/ratings/view/'.$model.'/'.$id.'/'.base64_encode(json_encode(array('name' => $name, 'config' => $config))), array('return'));' So I think this is already requesting the action and it is rendering the view.

Comment: But as I understood your question, you continually want to load a new rating element when a new song is loaded. Did I understand that wrong?

Comment: Yes. Actually I have created a function in the controller called song Rating and is accessing it like this :                                 `    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'category_details/songRating',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response.toSource());
        }
     });`                                                                 and my songRating contains this code in the question without echo and the line you have given with my element name.notworking

Comment: I take it that by 'my songRating' you mean the view file?

Comment: Actually I have fixed it. I have assinged the values to the element using the set() method and is working. Now it is showing the rating. but don't know why, I am not able to change the rating.